# php 25 hours in a day

Tags: php, datetime

I met strange behavior in PHP:

```
(strtotime("2017-11-05 00:00:00") - strtotime("2017-11-06 00:00:00")) / 24//3600
(strtotime("2017-11-06 00:00:00") - strtotime("2017-11-05 00:00:00")) / 24//3750
(strtotime("2017-11-07 00:00:00") - strtotime("2017-11-06 00:00:00")) / 24//3600
```

As I discover, it related to time shift from summer to winter time (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york). Is it correct behavior? I can't see anything related to it in docs. Anybody have a link?

At least, in java it work as I expect:

```
System.out.println(((new Date(2017, 11, 6).getTime()) - (new Date(2017, 11, 5).getTime())) / 24);//3600000
```

And now a question. How I can define, that this day is 25 hours, and I should handle this date by special approach?

Comment: Yes, it is correct behaviour: Certain days of the year have 25 hours, others have 23.... it all depends on your timezone, and whether daylight savings applies or not.

Comment: The easiest way to handle  it is to work purely with UTC timezone internally, and adjust to a user's timezone only for actual display or input

Comment: Or you can check if you are in daylight saving time or not and adjust your code accordingly : `if (date('I', time())){ //In DST }else{ //Not in DST }`

Comment: Thanks, `date('I'` looks good.

Comment: Unix timestamps are UTC, but PHP adjusts their display based on the timezone setting in php.ini (or modified by code). It's generally a better idea to work with DateTime  objects that are timezone-aware, and where you have much more control over how they handle timezone differences and the shifts to/from daylight savings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot speak to the PHP portion of your Question, I can correct your Java code.

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.NOVEMBER , 5 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ) , 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.NOVEMBER , 5 ).plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ) 
).toString()
```

> PT25H

```
Duration.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.NOVEMBER , 5 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) , 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.NOVEMBER , 5 ).plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) 
).toString()
```

> PT24H

A day in **UTC is always 24-hours** in length. A day in **some time zones may be 23, 24, 25** or some other number of hours, and may even include a partial (fractional) hour.

## Details

You are using the wrong classes for Java, and you were ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. The `java.util.Date` class is confusing, troublesome, and fortunately, now legacy. The modern java.time classes supplant those old date-time classes.

You ignore the crucial issue of time zone in your example code. That legacy `Date` class is always in UTC, but you care about `America/New_York` time zone. Your code is calculating 24 hours for a generic 24-hour day (UTC) while actually the 2017-11-05 in `America/New_York` is 25 hours rather than 24.

Your example code for Java makes no sense to me, as you are calculating a duration in milliseconds and then dividing by 24. I do not see how that division helps.

The number of milliseconds in a generic 24 hour day = ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1,000 ) = 86400000. That is number returned by your code using `java.util.Date` if we eliminate the division by 24.

```
long millis = ((new Date(2017, 11, 6).getTime()) - (new Date(2017, 11, 5).getTime())) ;
System.out.println( millis );
```

> 86400000

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/UhKtH9).

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.NOVEMBER , 5 ) ;
```

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).
Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Let java.time determine the first moment of the day. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at a time such as 01:00.

```
ZonedDateTime start = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Usually the Half-Open approach is best for defining a span of time. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a full day is defined as starting at the first moment of the day and running up to, but not including, the first moment of the following day.

```
ZonedDateTime stop = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate the length of that day, November 5th in New York zone.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

> PT25H

So, yes, we see a day that is 25 hours long because of the DST cut-over.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/TbLpXI).

That output from `Duration::toString` is in [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).